# Spring Boot returns 404 for static resources with docker

Tags: java, angular, docker, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot with docker. I have static resources in spring boot project and when I runt it with mvn spring:boot run everything works fine and resources are available. But when I create docker image from it using command

```docker
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD /target/example-*.jar /
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT java -jar example-*.jar
```

Then my static resources are not available by the localhost:8080. App started successfully(no errors in logs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources in a jar file can be tricky.

#### Here are some tips for trouble shooting:

1. Is the url for the 404 the same with both methods of deployment?
2. Inspect the jar file used in docker, are your resources even there?
3. Try running the jar file without docker, I suspect your resources
   are missing. If missing, you need to get maven to push them to the jar and you are probably not following the springboot conventions for resources.

Here is what worked for me when I needed to include a full springboot app as a dependency in a parent application:

#### Location

- Resources => src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/static
- View Templates => src/main/resources/WEB-INF/templates

#### If MVC, make sure you map your resources:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:META-INF/resources/static/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:META-INF/");
}
```

#### Also needed some changes to my gradle build:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M7'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.9.RELEASE'
        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.6.RELEASE'
    }
}

ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M7'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
//apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'

group = 'com.example.app'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

configurations {
    includeInJar
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates')
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy')

    includeInJar("org.webjars:bootstrap:4.0.0")
    includeInJar("org.webjars:jquery:3.3.1")
    configurations.compile.extendsFrom(configurations.includeInJar)
}

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = true
    }
}

jar {
    from configurations.includeInJar.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}

compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)
```

Comment: the trickiest thing that everything works fine if I just use run this jar without docker.

Comment: but you are correct - the main thing which fixes problem is to put all resources under src/main/resources/static folder.

Comment: I have a similar issues with docker and resources but resources are uploaded so it can't be store in `src/main/resources/static` folder, if you guys got a clue for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019493/spring-boot-1-5-9-404-error-while-accessing-resources-images-in-production  thanks in advance