# Spring boot 1.5.9, 404 error while accessing resources images within Docker container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc, spring-security

In a Spring Boot 1.5.9 application I want to access static resources through HTTP using Google Chrome.

In Docker I have **`404` error**, it worked fine in embedded tomcat.

### Configuration

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
VOLUME /tmp

RUN addgroup -S spring --gid 13371 && adduser -S spring -G spring --uid 13371
RUN mkdir -p /srv/upload
RUN chown -R spring:spring /srv/upload

ADD *.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'

USER spring:spring

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Duser.timezone=UTC","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

This is how I configure the static resources:

```java
public class MyWebMvcConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { 
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:upload/images/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

### Result

This is the result log when I access the URL from chrome **in docker** `http://localhost:8080/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png`

```sh
Counting up[http-nio-8080-Acceptor-0] latch=1
Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@45deea1:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@68f517c7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:47510]], Read from buffer: [0]
Received [GET /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,ru-RU;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5,vi-VN;q=0.4,vi;q=0.3

]
Security checking request GET /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png
  No applicable constraints defined
 Not subject to any constraint
Bound request context to thread: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@1f960fc1
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/oauth/token'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/oauth/token_key'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/oauth/check_token'
No matches found
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/favicon.ico']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/favicon.ico'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/favicon.png']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/favicon.png'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/login']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/login'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/logout'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/ping']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/ping'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/authorize']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/oauth/authorize'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/cb/**']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/cb/**'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/public/**']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/public/**'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/resources/**']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/resources/**'
matched
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
Set encoding to ISO-8859-1
No HttpSession currently exists
No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1877aac3
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/logout'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
Request 'GET /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png' doesn't match 'POST /logout
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
Request 'GET /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
Request 'GET /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
No matches found
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
Request 'GET /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png' doesn't match 'POST /login
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/logout'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
Request 'GET /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png' doesn't match 'POST /logout
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
Request 'GET /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
Request 'GET /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
No matches found
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/favicon.ico'
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/favicon.png'
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/ping'
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/public/**'
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png'; against '/resources/**'
Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png; Attributes: [permitAll]
Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6f01175d, returned: 1
Authorization successful
RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png
looking up handler for path: /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png]
Matching patterns for request [/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png] are [/resources/**, /**]
URI Template variables for request [/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png] are {}
Mapping [/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[URL [file:upload/images/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@6f49d153]]] and 1 interceptor
Last-Modified value for [/resources/promotions/37/lg/31723d95-eec3-4ff9-aa42-e3477559e9df.png] is: -1
SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
Successfully completed request
Chain processed normally
SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
Cleared thread-bound request context: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@1f960fc1
Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
Looking up handler method for path /error
looking up handler for path: /error
Did not find handler method for [/error]
Looking up handler method for path /error
Did not find handler method for [/error]
Looking up handler method for path /error
Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'error'
Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@351e414e] based on requested media type 'text/html'
Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@351e414e] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
Successfully completed request
 Disabling the response for further output
Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@45deea1:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@68f517c7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:47510]], Read from buffer: [0]
Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@45deea1:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@68f517c7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:47510]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
```

### Expected

This is what I expect (in the development environment) while accessing `http://localhost:8080/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg`

```sh
Counting up[http-nio-8080-Acceptor-0] latch=1
Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4d64a855:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@3eaf8ba0:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:59330]], Read from buffer: [0]
Received [GET /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,ru-RU;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5,vi-VN;q=0.4,vi;q=0.3

]
Security checking request GET /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg
  No applicable constraints defined
 Not subject to any constraint
Bound request context to thread: org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper@29e45b2
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg'; against '/'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/public/**']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg'; against '/public/**'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/resources/**']
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg'; against '/resources/**'
matched
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
Set encoding to ISO-8859-1
No HttpSession currently exists
No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@204c4db
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg'; against '/logout'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
Request 'GET /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg' doesn't match 'POST /logout
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
Request 'GET /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
Request 'GET /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
No matches found
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
Request 'GET /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg' doesn't match 'POST /login
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
No matches found
g/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg'; against '/public/**'
Checking match of request : '/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg'; against '/resources/**'
Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg; Attributes: [permitAll]
Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@199cd81c, returned: 1
Authorization successful
RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg
looking up handler for path: /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg]
Looking up handler method for path /resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg
Did not find handler method for [/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg]
Matching patterns for request [/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg] are [/resources/**, /**]
URI Template variables for request [/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg] are {}
Mapping [/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[URL [file:upload/images/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@49a0fe14]]] and 1 interceptor
Last-Modified value for [/resources/promotions/39/lg/843291ef-2309-4809-9f37-38257e087a97.jpeg] is: -1
SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
Successfully completed request
```

### Investigation

I have replicated the production environment locally and I used the same absolute path `file:/srv/upload/images` in development, I can confirm that status code are different within docker and without it:

- In embedded tomcat: 200
- In docker: 404

The problem is not related to the path being different but only because of docker.

### Question

- Is there a step I have forgotten?

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: I just added 100 reputation bounty reward, Let me know if I can add any further details, and please do not hesitate to upvote if you feel like this question is well formated

Comment: Those logs look like spring security logs and it doesn't seem to be a problem with authentication/authorization. Both logs show `Authorization successful` and `Mapping [/resources/promotions/[...].png] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[URL [file:upload/images/], ...`, so the path seems to be mapped correctly to the resource handler.

Comment: Do you have multiple docker containers running? Are they in the same network?

Comment: No I have only one service like this running. I use `--net host` and I  can reach the PostgreSQL database and the LDAP database without issue.

Comment: How did you start container? Can we see used `Dockerfile` and `docker info` output, pls?

Comment: Why you don't use absolute path `.addResourceLocations("file:/srv/upload/images/")`? You are in the container, so working directory can be different = relative path can be a problem.

Comment: Just edited the question with the `Dockerfile`, I have tried both, absolute and relative path, the issue remain. Usually, in development I use relative path  it work fine, I can upload and serve the file. In docker, I can only upload but not serve it. In production, I use absolute path, both development and production have the same issue so I doubt the problem is the absolute/relative difference. In order to simplify the investigation, I am now using `/srv/upload` in both development and production.

Comment: Are you sure the directory is where spring expects it to be? Have you used bash to check out the directory structure of a running container after uploading something?

Comment: Yes, I did get into the container and check that file were there. It is worth to say once again that file are being uploaded by the spring boot application into those folders.  Which means the process is having write permissions, and thous should have read permissions.

Comment: The same configuration is being executed locally (without docker), each time, the directory tested is the same. I think the investigation needs to go further. If you know how I can prove that file exist on the hard drive, please give me a test that you are willing me to execute, so we can leave this assumption behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation points to make a comment, so I write my comment as an answer :(

I had a similar issue with docker and resources, so I would like to help you.

Could you provide logs with `TRACE` level? 
This level helps us to see what is going on inside `PathResourceResolver` and according to this [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.3.x/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/PathResourceResolver.java) trace is used in most cases.

In my case, it was useful and helped me.

According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-console-output)

> You can enable a “trace” mode by starting your application with a --trace flag (or trace=true in your application.properties)

Comment: Hi and thanks, what was the  issue in your docker case ?

Comment: There was no issue with the docker. But before enabling tracing I had thought about an issue with docker.

In my case, I have had an issue with decoding URL. That URL had some encoded symbols.

After enabling trace logging I have gotten log record which contained some like this:  `path contains "../" after decoding`

I'm not sure that is your case but tracing can help with understanding how path resolver works in your case.

Comment: Thanks danil, yes increasing the `trace` LEVEL helped me to understand that I was having a permission issue, despire the volume mounted is `/srv/upload` owned by spring and that in my `Dockerfile` I have `RUN addgroup -S spring --gid 13371 && adduser -S spring -G spring --uid 13371 && mkdir -p /srv/upload && chown -R spring:spring /srv/upload` then `USER spring:spring, the directory was owned by the wrong user and writing of the file was failing